# jQuery Scroll Path

Tags: javascript, jquery

Would anyone know of a way to make this site (http://joelb.me/scrollpath/) auto play onLoad and continue to play/repeat? Someone wants to use this scroll path a s welcome screen in their business lobby (with added effects obviously). Thanks

Comment: You can call .trigger("click") method on elements leading to next steps. See http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ for details.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation here: https://github.com/JoelBesada/scrollpath lists "scrollTo". Simply call this on your scroller and you should be able to programmatically scroll.

Comment: Sorry Tarwin I'm new to Javascript and trying to learn. I'm totally lost st this point. Would I just wrap this in a <script> </script> and if so, where would I place it?

Comment: Can you post your HTML and JavaScript so far? (just the stuff that matters). There must be a place where you are calling something such as:

$('#myDiv').scrollPath(...);

Comment: Not sure how to post all the script. I guess what I have is too long. It is the same exact code as (http://joelb.me/scrollpath/). Sorry, you may have to do an inpsect element. Id there a certain I should past my code on Stackflow for further reference?

Comment: In the demo code @ http://joelb.me/scrollpath/script/demo.js look at this: // Include the jQuery easing plugin (http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/)
   // for extra easing functions like the one below
   $.fn.scrollPath("scrollTo", target, 1000, "easeInOutSine");

Comment: It's included. Is there something in the demo.js I need to change/add to make this animate? Seems like there some more code I need somewhere. What am I missing?